# Switch window configuration layout with names

Tags: emacs, window

The winner-mode configure window layout with functions of `winner-redo` and `winner-undo`.

Is it possible to name the current configuration window layout, then I could browser all the layouts by name and switch between them purposely.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can [*bookmark*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#windowConfig) any window configuration (or frame configuration or...).

You can then switch among your saved configurations by just jumping to their bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use registers for this purpose:

To name a window configuration, simply: <kbd>C-x r w</kbd>`letter/number`

Then, to jump b/w named configurations: <kbd>C-x r j</kbd>`id`

Note: those are the default bindings for `window-configuration-to-register` and `jump-to-register`, which I would simplify if you start to use registers commonly.  They are extremely useful, letting you jump b/w all sorts of configurations/points/etc.

If you have common things you want to be defaults in registers, you could add that to your init.